# Copy-pasted answer, declined flag

Tags: support, declined-flags, specific-answer

After posting an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710115/how-to-get-correct-if-statement-with-similar-words/57710405), a few minutes later my answer was [copy-pasted by a new account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57710405/789671). Sometime after that but before the flag was reviewed, the nature of the question was clarified and my answer was rewritten. When the flag was eventually reviewed, it was declined with the following message:

> This is not actually copy/pasted (the suggested code differs a bit) and they were posted within minutes of each other. If you think this adds nothing over your answer, down/delete vote, don't flag.

The reviewer didn't check my [answer's history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57710276/1), as it was definitely a copy-paste of my original answer. The only differences are that it omitted the line of code at the end and didn't bother to redo the markup.

Comment: I've taken an opportunity to flag this and describe a bit more: *"Plagiarism: This copies directly from the first revision of the other answer."*.

Comment: What kind of flag did you raise? If it was NAA, you should have mod flagged

Comment: @Machavity I flagged "in need of moderator intervention".

Comment: @Machavity I don't think you can add a message to NAA flags.

Comment: Using an earlier version of the answer to plagiarize is something I’ve not seen. In the future be sure you call that out explicitly. “Just copy and pasted my answer” is a text we get a lot, and it’s easy to ignore since people use that same line to say “user x covers the same ground as my answer so you should delete it”, which for reasons of fairness we stay away from. Plagiarism is a magic word; say it and link to the specific instance of plagiarism and we will handle it.

Comment: @TheWanderer mods can decline any flag with a custom message. The Q mentions nothing about the flag type

Comment: @Machavity sorry, I thought you were responding to JL

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Well, at the time the copy was made (and I flagged it), it was the current version of my answer. I didn't know I'd be rewriting my answer at that time. But understood... in the future I'll use the magic word.

Comment: @glibdud that’s an accident of the time delay between flagging and when we are able to handle them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm the moderator who declined the flag. Sorry about that -- I had missed the earlier revision of your answer that was indeed identical.

It looks like the post got cleaned up by another mod.